# When is a singleton class allocated in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, singleton

In MRI Ruby, when is a singleton class allocated?

I just found out that a singleton class can also have its own singleton class.

Thusly, it's possible to call

```
Object.singleton_class.singleton_class.singleton_class.singleton_class...
```

until the end of time itself. Obviously all of these singleton classes aren't allocated by the virtual machine by default.

Exactly when does a singleton class get allocated by the Ruby virtual machine? Does an object have a singleton class at all if I don't define any methods on it and don't call `Object#singleton_class`?

Comment: Is this not merely an implementation issue? Does it matter if a singleton class is created when an object is created or when the object's singleton class is first referenced?

Answer (score 5):

From the point of view of a Ruby program, every object always has a singleton class. Including classes. Including singleton classes.

However, as you guessed, some Ruby Implementations optimize this by not allocating all singleton classes in advance.

Here's what YARV does (to the best of my knowledge):

1. Singleton classes are allocated lazily. They are only created when you either try to access it, or open it, or define a method or constant or variable in it. This is a *memory optimization*.
2. However, this lazy allocation has some overhead. Since modules and classes often have singleton methods, for classes and modules, this is different: for classes and modules, YARV creates a singleton class as soon as the (class / module) object is instantiated. This is a *speed optimization*.
3. Of course, as you said in your question, this leads to an infinite recursion. So, #2 is only applied to "normal" classes, not to singleton classes.

So: singleton classes are instantiated lazily. The exception are classes and modules. The exception from the exception are singleton classes.

However, let me repeat what I wrote at the beginning: this is a *private internal implementation detail* of YARV. Other Ruby Implementations may or may not behave the same.

In *Ruby*, a singleton class always exists for every object, including singleton classes.

Comment: AFAIK, when a class includes a module, the module is inserted into that class'es ancestor chain, but the module's singleton class is not inserted into the class'es singleton class'es ancestor chain, why? Is that related to the singleton class'es lazy allocation strategy?

Comment: YARV 2.6.5 seems not obeying the optimization rules. When I run `ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).count` in a fresh irb, it returns 652. When I run this expression after I defined a class `A`, it returns 653. When I run this again after I run `A.singleton_class`, it returns 654. Same behavior for modules. So it seems singleton classes are all lazily allocated.

Comment: "Is that related to the singleton class'es lazy allocation strategy" – It cannot possibly be related to that, because it's an optimization, and optimizations are not allowed to change the semantics of the language. (Otherwise, they wouldn't be optimizations.) This is simply how the default semantics of `Module#append_features` are defined.

Comment: "YARV 2.6.5 seems not obeying the optimization rules." – Interesting. It might have been an article about MRI that I was reading then.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** according to my experiment, at least for YARV 2.6.5, **all singleton classes are lazily allocated.**

**Before experiment**

- `ObjectSpace.each_object(type)` returns an enumerator that iterates over all the objects that `.is_a?(type)`, as long as it is not garbage collected yet.

**Experiment 1: defining an empty class**

Open an irb, and do following steps. Note that the absolute number of objects may vary on your computer, but it's the diff that matters.

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).count  #=> 649

class A; end

ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).count  #=> 650
```

Defining an empty class only allocates 1 class object, so the singleton class is not allocated.

**Experiment 2: defining a class containing only instance methods**

```
class B
  def foo; end
  def bar; end
end

ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).count  #=> 651
```

Creating such classes does not create singleton classes either.

**Experiment 3: defining a class containing class methods**

```
class C
  def self.foo; end
end

ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).count  #=> 653
```

This time, 2 classes are created, one is the class `C` itself, the other is `C`'s singleton class.

**Experiment 4: new objects**

```
a = A.new

ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).count  #=> 653
```

So instantiation does not create singleton classes.

**Experiment 5: adding singleton methods**

```
def a.foo; end

ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).count  #=> 654
```

As expected, adding singleton methods does create singleton classes.

**Experiment 6: inheritance**

```
class D; end

class E < D
  def self.foo; end
end

ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).count  #=> 658
```

This time, 4 classes are allocated, 2 of which are the "normal" classes, the other 2 are singleton classes. Because we proved that creating empty classes do not allocate singleton classes on the fly, `D`'s singleton class must be allocated when defining singleton methods in `E`. So the conclusion is, when a singleton class must be created, its parent class (also a singleton class) must already be there. If not, it's created on the fly.

You can do the experiments for modules by yourself.